# C++ Errors in constructors

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I've got a problem with my code.
I've got a class called Player which looks like this

```
class Player
{
public:
   ...
Player();
Player(string firstName, string lastName, int birthYear);
~Player();
   ...
};
```

My source.cpp looks like this

```
string firstName = ...;
string lastName = ...;
int birth = ...

Player team[x](firstName, lastName, birth); // <--- This is were I get my errors
```

My errors are saying

```
error C3074: an array can only be initialized with an initializer-list

error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0

error C2057: expected constant expression
```

The constructor I want to use is `Player(string firstName, string lastName, int birthYear)`. I think that I might be using the default constructor in source.cpp

I want to create 5x Player team[x](firstName, lastName, birth)

But this is where I get my errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your code here.  Which of those errors is confusing you?

Comment: I tried to. But when I use the code function on this page, and then copy my code, it just puts a code snippet around 1 line. I don't fancy copying all of my lines. Is there a better way to copy code to this page?

Comment: @user3194111 select code, copy, come here, paste, adjust indent. Look at the help options for information about formatting.

Comment: Select code -> Ctrl+K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line simply isn't valid:

```
Player team[x](firstName, lastName, birth); // <--- This is were I get my errors
```

It doesn't make sense.  You're trying to declare an array and call a constructor at the same time.  You already created your `team` array.  If you want to create a `Player` and assign it then you would use:

```
team[x] = Player(firstName, lastName, birth);
```

Of course, you already created a bunch of them (default initialized) when you created the array in the first place. Since this is C++, use a `std::vector<Player>`.

---

Also, something that is wrong but is not generating an error:

```
int matches;
int* dates = new int[matches];
```

Here, `matches` is uninitialized and its value is indeterminate. Reading that variable invokes undefined behavior, and certainly you don't want any random size for your array (why aren't you using a vector again?) You need to initialize `matches` before using it.

Comment: Thanks. I've never used vectors, that's why. I'll google around and look for it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your code is that the variable `matches` hasn't been initialized and has an indeterminate value.

```
int matches;
int* dates = new int[matches];
```

You should initialize `matches` before calling `new int[matches]`.

A `team` of `nrOfPlayers` players is constructed when you allocated an array of `Players`:

```
Player* team = new Player[nrOfPlayers];
```

You can now fill in a player's information by creating a temporary `Player` object and assigning it to an element in `team`. This will call `Player`'s implicitly defined *copy assignment operator*:

Replace line 75 with:

```
team[x] = Player(firstName, lastName, birth); // copy constructor is called
```

Comment: "This is happening because you're trying to allocate an array of integers with the variable matches which hasn't been defined." - That's not true.  `matches` is uninitialized and has an indeterminate value, and reading it is UB, but that is not a compiler error.  The size error comes from this line- `Player team[x](firstName, lastName, birth);`

Comment: @EdS. Thanks for pointing that out. I revised my entry to reflect your correction.

Comment: Okay. The player constructor works now. The problem now is - as you mentioned - the int dates[matches]. My idea was to put int* dates = new int[matches] the line below sas >> matches; However, that did not work. I got some linking errors

Comment: @user3194111: What is the type of `sas`?